# AMCharts - Dynamically add children to tree map

Tags: amcharts, treemap

I am thoroughly enjoying AMChart's many features but I couldn't find any way to dynamically add some children to a treemap.

I am trying to load additional children on "hit" for each element

```
  for (var i = 0; i < this.maxDepthLevel; i++) {
    const series = this.chart.seriesTemplates.create(i);
    series.columns.template.events.on("hit", async function(ev) {
      const data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext;
      children = await api.getChildrenOf(data.id);
      ev.target.dataItem.treeMapDataItem.children.values.push(...children);
    });
  }
```

^ this doesn't work and when doing this and then zooming out, I get

[image]

I even tried changing the underlying data and then calling

```
  this.chart.invalidateRawData();
```

but to no avail.

Does anyone have any experience with adding such dynamic children to a tree map?
I cannot simply load everything upfront, there are far too many possible layers of depth unfortunately and the request will be too large!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly pushing child items to children values you need to do it like this :

```
for(var index=0; index < children.length; index++){
    var newChildDataItem = new am4charts.TreeMapDataItem();
    newChildDataItem.value = children[index].value;
    newChildDataItem.name = children[index].name;
    newChildDataItem.color = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.color;
    ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.children.insert(newChildDataItem);
}
```